# How to solve error in Access design view for working SQL join expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

The following query works in Access when entered in SQL-view, but gives an error when changing to Design view:
`microsoft access can't represent the join expression in design view`

```
INSERT INTO DB_ADGB ( ADGID, AID, BID, IsLQ )
SELECT tblALL.fldDgmId AS ADGID, NAAs.AID, tblCommonB.ID AS BID, False AS IsLQ
FROM NAAs, tblALL 
INNER JOIN tblCommonB 
ON tblALL.fldMixLoadNr_2 & tblALL.fldMLCN = tblCommonB.B
WHERE (((NAAs.ATypeId)=8) AND ((tblALL.fldMLCN)<>"OK"))
ORDER BY tblALL.fldDgmId;
```

The problem appears to be on the following line:

```
ON tblALL.fldMixLoadNr_2 & tblALL.fldMLCN = tblCommonB.B
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same but which does not err when viewing in design?

In brief, my goal is to generate a query that retrieves values from the A.ID column if the combination of values from B.A and B.B are present in the A.CODE column.

Comment: Is that '&' supposed to be string concatenation? I'm not sure but you can of course just leave the query in sql view and save it as is. As I remember, you don't have to have a query be expressible in design view for it to work.

Comment: The & is indeed a string concatenation. Thing is that when you open the query in design-view (unintentionally) the error appears, the correct query is changed by access and the original query is lost

Comment: build a view on tblAll which concats the field then in this query use that view instead of table all.  but i'm not sure that's the problem.  you're mixing join notation.  you shouldn't use a `,` notation and `inner join` syntax in the same query. `FROM NAAs, tblAll INNER JOIN... `  I'd prefer not to use the , notation instead use INNER JOIN if that's really what you want.

Comment: Um... How does NAAS relate to tblAll or did you really mean cross join?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your problem. The query can be saved, ran, opened for editing (it opens in SQL view - I would leave it that way), then put into design view, then ran, put back in SQL view, etc.

Or let's put this another way - yes, that error message appears which says `microsoft access can't represent the join expression in design view` but it does not stop the query from being ran, being saved, and being edited (in SQL view). So,in general, if you have written the query in SQL view and it cannot be expressed in designer view, then you just leave it in SQL view.

TLDR; Just roll with it.